# payone integration with creditcardcheck

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, payment, payone

I have read almost everything there is on the Internet (almost no examples) and studied the (very limited and confusing) documentation. 
I have a client were I am integrating payone, and I am not getting any further.

So I used the API client documentation and integrated the iframe client api example with creditcardcheck on page 35 (chapter 3.1.5.5). This works fine I receive the answer and a pseudocardpan.

As explained in the quick start guide, I then start the "preauthorization", using the server api with the pseudocardpan. I send all the necessary parameters again, and I end up on the server payone with status = approved .

I assume this is then successfull. However, what or how should I proceed? What is the transactionUrl for? Maybe someone has experience with payone.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to hear you're having a tough time implementing a Payone interface. We are currently working on providing more insightful examples. Please bear with us for a little longer.

Meanwhile, I'll gladly help you with continuing your integration. After the successful preauthorization, you'll need to store the txid for further reference to this transaction. To collect the money from the creditcard, you'll need to send a capture request with the amount you wish to collect and the txid as a reference (see the docs for a full list of required parameters).

If you don't want to send a capture request afterwards (for instance if you want to collect the entire amount immediately after the customer completed their order) you can send an authorization request instead of the preauthorization and leave out the capture part.

The transaction status URL is used to asynchronously inform your application about status changes in Payone transactions. For instance in a prepayment setting we'll send a PAID notification as soon as the customer paid the amount to your bank account.

Best,
Florian (Technical Partner Manager @ Payone)

Comment: Is there an example for the Frontend use case (see https://www.payone.com/plattform-integration/schnittstellen/) somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that once the response comes back that it has been approved, then it is approved - all the details were correct and authorisation was successful.

If you are doing a `preauthorization` then you will need to follow that with a `capture` to actually take the payment. In some legislative environments, for example many US states, you cannot capture the payment until you finally ship the goods from an online shop.

If that is not a problem (e.g. paying invoices, running an online shop in the UK), then use `authorization`, which does a `preauthorization` and `capture` all in one step. Apart from the name of the request, the details of the message you send is identical.